# Dropwizard + Halbuilder looking for message body writer

Tags: java, dropwizard, hal-json, halbuilder

I'm using dropwizard to build a Restful service. I'm using halbuilder to create json+hal media type. My resource is returning a representation with a few links on a get request. It works perfectly fine on my dev environment but when I deploy my service to heroku I get below exception:

```
2015-01-06T16:40:01.054739+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR [2015-01-06 16:40:00,966] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse: A message body writer for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/hal+json was not found.
2015-01-06T16:40:01.054760+00:00 app[web.1]: */* ->
2015-01-06T16:40:01.054762+00:00 app[web.1]:   com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
```

I would appreciate any help to fix this issue.